# Permalink and ACF field

Tags: title

I'm trying to get the thumbnail and title from permalink outside the main loop using ACF field:

```
<?php 
     $post_id = get_field('1_main_post');
     if( $post_id ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post_id); ?>">
          <div class="top_post">
            <div class="top_post_img">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post_cover' ); ?>
                  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
     <?php endif; ?>
?>
```

but I receive post_thumbnail and title from current page, not the selected page. Can someone look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use some different functions for obtaining the post thumbnail and title from outside of the loop:

`get_the_title( $post_id )` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

and

`get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post_cover' )` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

**Note**: These functions only return the title and post thumbnail so will need to be echoed out.